# Why does it give an error when compiling the project:

Tags: c++, memory

I need to display an array of structures, as far as I understand, I need to use a memory shift, having a pointer to the first element of the array. When trying to fix the code, we saw the following error:

> Invalid types ‘[int]’ for array subscript

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct Point3D{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}Point3D;

Point3D createPoint3D(double xnum, double ynum, double znum){//функція створення точки
    Point3D point;
    point.x = xnum;
    point.y = ynum;
    point.z = znum;
    return point;
}

void PrintPoint(Point3D point){//використовується в інщій ф-ції, по суті внутрішня не основна функція
    cout << "(" << point.x << ","<< endl;
    cout << point.y<< ","<< endl;
    cout << point.z<< ";"<< "\n"<< endl;
    }



class Obj3D{
private:

      Point3D *array_of_points;
      int number_of_points;
public:
        void setAddPoint(Point3D point){
            *(array_of_points + sizeof(point)*number_of_points) = point;
            number_of_points++;}

        int getNumber(){
            return number_of_points;}

        Point3D *getArray(){
        return array_of_points;}

        Obj3D(Point3D point, int number){
        number--;
        *(array_of_points + number) = point;}

        Obj3D(){
        *array_of_points = createPoint3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        number_of_points = 1;
        }

        ~Obj3D(){}
};

       void printObj(Obj3D Obj){
           for(int x = 0; x<=Obj.getNumber(); x++){
            PrintPoint(Obj.getArray()[x]);
           }
       }


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Obj3D Obj;
    Point3D point1 = createPoint3D(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5);
    Point3D point2 = createPoint3D(0.5,-0.5,-0.5);
    Point3D point3 = createPoint3D(-0.5,-0.5,0.5);
    Point3D point4 = createPoint3D(0.5,-0.5,0.5);
    Point3D point5 = createPoint3D(0.0,0.5,0.0);
    Obj.setAddPoint(point1);
    Obj.setAddPoint(point2);
    Obj.setAddPoint(point3);
    Obj.setAddPoint(point4);
    Obj.setAddPoint(point5);
    cout<<Obj.getArray();
    exit(0);
}
```

You can not watch the main function, it is most likely not correct, I want to deal with the functions of the output and set

Comment: Unrelated: You have a typo in `PrintPoint(Obj.getArray[x];` you're missing the closing `)` It should be `PrintPoint(Obj.getArray()[x]);`

Comment: Also use `#include <string>` instead of `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Don't add the suggestions given in the answer to your current question. It makes the answers obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely don't need to *memory shift*

```
*(array_of_points + sizeof(point)*number_of_points) = point;
```

C++ is not that complicated, just

```
array_of_points[number_of_points] = point;
```

Because the compiler knows the type involved, `Point3D`, it's quite capable of working out the memory shift by itself. Also by the rules of C++ `*(p + n)` is exactly equivalent to `p[n]` but generally prefer the latter because it is easier to read.

Other errors (which you'll find out when you run the code). Class `Obj3D` has an uninitialised pointer `array_of_points`. You use the pointer, e.g. here

```
Obj3D(){
    *array_of_points = createPoint3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    number_of_points = 1;
}
```

but you never give the pointer a value. So that is going to crash your program.

You need to allocate memory using `new` for your pointer to point at. That doesn't happen automatically. E,g,

```
Obj3D() {
    array_of_points = new Point3D[100]; // allocate 100 points
    array_of_points[0] = createPoint3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    number_of_points = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **problem**(besides the typo of missing `)`) is that you're not calling method `getArray` and instead using `operator[]`.

To **solve** this call the method `getArray` by replacing `Obj.getArray[x]` with `Obj.getArray()[x]` as shown below:

```
//---------------------vv---v---->parenthesis added for calling and also for closing
PrintPoint(Obj.getArray()[x]);
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/H3MQWSr6m)

Comment: thank you very much, but I still have a memory problem, do you think it's worth seeing the memory for this array at the beginning of the program, if so, please tell me how to do this

Comment: @DanilDubok You're welcome :) Feel free to ask a new separate question for your follow up questions.

Comment: @DanilDubok Don't add the suggestions given in the answer to your current question. It makes the answers obsolete.

Comment: @DanilDubok You're original question was something else and you're accepting answer for something else. Ask 1 question per post.